# laravel schedule is not working automatically

Tags: laravel, vps, laravel-scheduler

```
 protected $commands = [
    Commands\FetchAndStore::class,
    Commands\FeatchAndSrore2::class
];




protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('command:FetchAndStore')
             ->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('command:FeatchAndSrore2')
             ->everyMinute();
}
```

here is my code I ran this command `PHP artisan schedule:run` need a solution  for local server as well as VPS server

Comment: Set up a CRON task that runs `php artisan schedule:run`, or run `php artisan schedule:work` if you want it running locally, **exactly like it says in the documentation**: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

Comment: I don't know why it is not working